# Adobe Media Server Network Location for HTTP Streaming

Tags: windows, network-share, unc, flash-media-server, http-streaming

Running Adobe Media Server 4.5 on Windows Server 2008. I have a mapped network drive (Amazon S3 connected via Webdrive) where all my videos are stored. Using a UNC path, I can successfully stream via RTMP. However, when I try to use HTTP streaming, the videos will play for about one second and then I get an error. In my Apache error log, it says this:

[error] mod_jithttp [404]: [err=1] "c:\" does not exist

It appears as though it is adding "c:\" to the beginning of my UNC path. But my httpd.conf file must be correct if it at least works for a split second. What is going on? This is driving me nuts after finally getting all the permissions setup the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having the same problem, here's how I figured it out. Using forward slashes in my Apache config ended up fixing it.

However, if you are trying to mount an Amazon S3 account in Windows (via TNTDrive or Windrive), then when a user seeks forward in a video on your site, the server actually has to download the entire video up to that point, and then the user can see the rest. This is incredibly slow and inefficient.